# command "exp build:android", error "Can't find package.json"

Tags: react-native, expo

I run command exp build:android.
After some minutes it displays:

```
[exp] Building...
[exp] Build started, it may take a few minutes to complete.
[exp] Build ID: (some id here)
[exp] Run `exp build:status` to monitor it.
```

When I run command "exp build:status", I see this error:

```
|[exp] Error: Can't find package.json
/[exp] There is an error with your project. See above logs for information.
```

Do you have any idea what it could be. Package.json does exist in the project.

Update: exp is called at the project root (package.json is in same folder).
My project was created with "Create-react-native-app".
exp version: 46.0.3
nodejs version v6.11.2
npm version 3.10.10

Comment: Where did you call exp build? at root of your project? Which version of exp and npm your are using?

Comment: Same problem here with exp 49.0.3 any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the directory is case sensitive! For example: if you run "eas build" in a directory called "/App", but you're cd'ed into "/app", eas will package everything up with the wrong directory name.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "26.0.0",
    "name": "TongPos",
    "description": "your app desc",
    "android": {
      "package": "com.sohagfaruque.tongpos"
    }
  }

}
```

please update your app.json file like above mentioned. you must include

```
"android": {
      "package": "com.sohagfaruque.tongpos"
    } 
in your exp object
```